# make webpage counters work in redirects

Tags: php, jsp, counter

I'm writing a php program that redirects user to a page.(something like link shortener)
I want count pages visits without using mysql or etc. so I chose to work with a page counter service like histats but to make these services to work webpage has to be opened by user and a jsp or embeded flash has to be runned in user browser. but my program redirects user to another page that doesn't belongs to me and page on my domain wont be opened!
is there any way to make these counters to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot *normally* force the user to call the counter URL. Especially when you redirect the client via http. You may save the hits in a plain file or any other database.

You should also know that the user maybe blocks the counter with an adblocker when you use a please wait for redirection message. Instat of redirect directly.